# Angular, Node.js, MySQL image upload

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, blob

I want to send an image to `MySQL` blob feild using `node.js` and use `Angular` to display that blob as an image.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you upload image file on server and get its path and store that path in `MySQL` database.
for example if user wants to upload `test.jpg`
on server save it like : `server/images/test.jpg`
then insert saved path to `MySQL`
and on front-end retrieve image path and bind to `src` property of image tag.

saving blobs to database will result in slow response when you will fetch records.

you can see more details here: https://blog.jscrambler.com/implementing-file-upload-using-node-and-angular